# Multiple dinamic forms that become a single one

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms

Should be 4-5 forms that have some input types on each one ( like the second one has 3 select options where you can select your birthday).All of them are in a horizontal line .After completing one I can press the button "continue" and my current form go in background and the next one go in front( the current form is on spotlight) and the rest are in background.After I pressed continue the values of the form are shown on that form( like if I completed a text box and press continue,the text box with my data becomes an text on that form).In the last form are shown all the data from the previous 4/5 forms.

I can't use php,only basic js/css/html.
So how I can make that continue button and transport the data between forms?

Comment: are these requirement need to built .. what is problem

Comment: @Stallion I don't know how to transport the data from forms and how to make that continue button.I edited my post,thanks for observation

Comment: seeing your requirement you can add item into javascript variable either global or under some namespace then read the variable at last. 
your question is not good and your problem is vague but global variable solve your probelm

Comment: @Stallion Thanks ,but how I make that continue button with fade in effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS3 to animate stuff in a browser. But my suggestion is to not use many of them, because many animations could lead to a laggy browser.

Here are some examples:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animate_buttons.asp

Also the forms can be made invisible with css. If you use a bit of javascript you can trigger that event when a button is clicked.